# Migrating Wordpress Posts only while preserving pages, themes and plugins on the new one

Tags: wordpress

I have worked on a highly customized new blog with a custom theme(generatepress child theme) and plugins(elementor) with a few example posts to test it. Then I tried to import posts from my old blog but it just overwrites my theme setup and pages when I only want posts(with image attachments) seamlessly added to my new blog.

Or the other way around, importing my themes and plugins to the old one but that also didn't preserve my themes.

At least importing only posts, theoretically, shouldn't cause trouble as it is a single thing without any configuration to worry about and I have the theme working perfectly at least in my new blog.

In which way can I accomplish this?

Comment: have you tried the wordpress export and only export posts? https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/import-export-wordpress-website

Comment: Exporting posts also overwrites pages and theme customization for some reason.